# What, if any, is the relation between the Lie derivative and the Legendre transform?

Tags: mathematical-physics

I don't remember where I read it, or even if my memory serves me correctly, but I think that I read somewhere that the Lie derivative amounts to a Legendre transform. Is this true and, if it is, what is the relation between them?

Comment: I would be amazed if there were one! Do you have any idea what context you heard this in?

Comment: I vaguely remember in thermodynamics, if you take Lie derivative of a differential form on a 2*n+1 manifold, you get back the differential form times a partial derivative - which was the Legendre transform. We didn't use it much.

Comment: Here's the URL for the "Geometry of Thermodynamic Processes" - https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.04227. The paper uses the Lie derivative to compute Legendre transformations.

Comment: Thanks Cinaed. I downloaded the paper and will read it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

The connection between Lie derivative and Legendre transform arises
in the theory of [contact transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry) that was developed by Sophus Lie already some 150 years ago.

A good starting point is [1] together with small étude [2]:

> Recall that an ordinary first oder differential equation $f(x,y',y)=0$ has the following geometrical interpretation: The differential equation defines a surface $M_f$ of codimension one in the contact space $J^1(\mathbb R)$ with coordinates $(x,p,y)\,,$ $(p=y')\,,$ $$\tag{0.1}M_f=\{(x,p,y):f(x,p,y)=0\}$$ and the (generalized) solution of the equation is a curve $\ell=(x(t),p(t),y(t))$ belonging to this surface such that the contact form $$\tag{0.2}\boldsymbol{\omega}=p\,dx-dy$$ vanishes on the curve (the contact form (0.2) defines the distribution (not-integrable) of the planes that annihilate the form. The solution $\ell$ is the integral of this distribution).

> The Legendre transformation $$\tag{0.3}\tilde x=p\,,\;\tilde p=-x\,,\;\tilde y=y-p\,x\,,$$ of the contact space $J^1(\mathbb R)$ preserves the contact form.

The proof is trivial:
$$
\tilde p\,d\tilde x-d\tilde y=-x\,dp-dy+x\,dp+p\,dx=p\,dx-dy=\boldsymbol{\omega}\,.
$$
The connection with the Lie derivative is the following: The Legendre transformation (0.3) gives rise to a
a vector field
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{v}=x\,\partial_x+y\,\partial_y=\tilde p\,\partial_\tilde p+\tilde y\,\partial_\tilde y\,.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
{\cal L}_\boldsymbol{v}\,\boldsymbol{\omega}&=d(\iota_\boldsymbol{v}\,\boldsymbol{\omega})+\iota_\boldsymbol{v}\,(d\boldsymbol{\omega})=d(-y+p\,x)+\iota_\boldsymbol{v}\,(dp\wedge dx)\\[2mm]
&=-dy+p\,dx+x\,dp-x\,dp=\boldsymbol{\omega}\,.
\end{align}
Likewise, in Legendre transformed coordinates,
\begin{align}
{\cal L}_\boldsymbol{v}\,\boldsymbol{\omega}&=d(\iota_\boldsymbol{v}\,\boldsymbol{\omega})+\iota_\boldsymbol{v}\,(d\boldsymbol{\omega})=d(-\tilde{y})+\iota_\boldsymbol{v}\,(d\tilde p\wedge d\tilde x)\\[2mm]
&=-d\tilde y+\tilde p\,d\tilde x=\boldsymbol{\omega}\,.
\end{align}

In the modern theory, contact transformations are such vector fields
whose Lie derivative multiplies the contact form only by a scalar function.

[1] [S.G. Rajeev, A Hamilton-Jacobi Formalism for Thermodynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4319).

[2] [H. Khudaverdian, Symmetries of the Clairaut Equation](https://khudian.net/Etudes/Geometry/infinlegendre.pdf).